# Configure apache 2.4.3 for CGI scripting on windows

Tags: apache, perl, configuration, cgi

After going through many outdated post. Still have issues to configure apache server on my widows 7 PC.
Any help.
getting following error:
`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /test.pl on this server.`

logfile:
`[Wed Mar 12 11:31:11.500316 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 2008:tid 1048] [client ::1:57646] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/htdocs/test.pl`
where to add ExecCGI in apache 2.4.3 httpd.conf file.
path:`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\cgi-bin`

Is it is necessary to install 'mod_perl'?
How to configure apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to install mod_perl.  But your Perl program must have a shebang line at the top to that it can be run form the command line as 'test.pl'

Typically we do not put our CGI programs in the document root (`htdocs`).

Look in your Apache config, and you'll likely find come configuration for a directory called `cgi-bin`, that will the ExecCGI arribute set.  In your case it looks like:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\cgi-bin
```

Place your program there. Make sure that your program is executable by apache's user.
Look further in the config file for a ScriptAlias setting that maps the cgi-bin directory to a URI. Typically this defaults to /cgi-bin.

Bounce apache, and then visit http://your.site/cgi-bin/test.pl

Comment: how to set ExecCGI attribute in httpd.conf

Comment: Did you find an existing cgi-bin configuration setting? if you did, it probably already had ExecCGI set in its Options line.  The best way to learn Apache config is to read an existing config and look up each line in the docs to figure out what it's doing.